# Xero previewer not displaying Employees

Tags: xero-api

I am setting up a Xero payroll integration using an Australian demo company.  I have set up a private api key and using the previewer to check the responses to retrieving all employees.

There are 6 test employees and when I use the following endpoint https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/employees no employee data is returned but I get a 200 response.

If I post data through the Previewer using the same endpoint, contacts are successfully created but are not in the Payroll Employees list but rather in the contacts list.

Using a get on the above endpoint after this point will then return any Employee created through the Post in the Previewer. Those alone.

When I set up the API key there was an option to enable for Payroll and I did do this.

Anyone know why I'm not getting the 6 Employees in the Employee list please?

Many thanks
Cath

Answer (score 0):

found it:  wrong endpoint was being used.  This was the correct one.

https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees